# Pagemap data and Google Structured Data Validator tool

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm trying to get back pagemap data when I call the google site search api, and it's not currently present.

The sample response here leads me to believe it is possible ( there is a pagemap field )
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list?hl=en

Can anyone confirm that the structured data tool reads PageMap data? I've tried using it to verify my pagemap data is correct, but finds nothing.

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

If it doesn't, does the Site search API only return pagemap attributes maybe at the paid level?

Comment: Same issue here with the Structured Data Testing tool not validating Pagemap data (at least not in sitemaps).

Comment: Having used the paid version of GSS I also confirm that the JSON response contains a Pagemap object with structured data Google understands about the page. We did a test and had some structured data implemented with Schema.org via page source, these were reflect present in GSS pagemap objects. We did another test to use `JSON-LD` data instead and this wasn't picked up (we tested on Feb 14)

Answer (score 0):

Answering below question:
**If it doesn't, does the Site search API only return pagemap attributes maybe at the paid level?**

Yes. It gives you a `pagemap` object which itself is sub-divided in other data objects. For instance the `book:isbn` was provided as `Schema.org` data, whereas the `og:` stuff as Open Graph Data.

[image]